# How do TCP state transitions occur?

Tags: c++, c, tcp, packet, state-machine

This link explains the [TCP State Machine](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm). It lists all the state transitions based on send/receive events. I feel like it only describes the obvious ones. I'd like to know what happens when you're in a LISTEN state and you receive a DATA packet, or when you're in a ESTABLISHED state and you receive a SYN.

Are there any implementations of TCP in c/c++ available, WINSOCK library or others?
The [TCP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) document is nice and all, but implementation would be much more helpful, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent resource for what you want:

1995 - TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 2: The Implementation (with Gary R. Wright) - ISBN 0-201-63354-X

Comment: I went and borrowed the book at my University's library and indeed it is very comprehensive and addresses most of my concerns with state changes and how to actually process individual packets. Thanks, accepted answered.

Answer (score 3):

In the description of any networking protocol (state machine, etc) it is fairly safe to assume that packets which are invalid for a given state are just going to be discarded. If the stack gets a SYN in the middle of an established TCP stream (with the source/dest IP:PORT matching that stream) it's probably some spoofing attack, or a corruption that the header checksum did not catch. The packet should be tossed on the floor without any update to the state.

I don't suspect that it would be useful to explicitly include cases like that in the description of the TCP state machine. That would be like including every possible syntax error in the grammar description of a language: cluttered, large and confusing.

Comment: +1, it's perfectly reasonable to include only states/events that generate valid actions.  There may, or may not, be some para. somewhere that says all other cases result in no action.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the [TCP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) is a very informative read.

You asked about implementation, so here are a few resources you might be interested in:

- [lwIP: A lightweight TCP/IP Stack (Open source)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip)
- [Linux Kernel Source (Contains multiple TCP implementations)](http://www.kernel.org/)

lwIP focuses on minimizing resource usage, and there is a [paper (PDF)](http://www.sics.se/~adam/lwip/doc/lwip.pdf) that has been published detailing how it achieves this. The paper details implementation as well, which might answer some of your questions above. The Linux Kernel provides a complete implementation and some more specific implementations of the stack. It is admittedly harder to navigate the source code, due to its complexity, but is probably the most complete open source implementation you can find.